# Checkbox for terms and conditions in an email

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a method to have customer tick a terms and conditions acceptance box over gmail email. Is there anyway to do this?

We are also looking for a method of having a 'pay now' option thats only clickable when the ticks the checkbox. The 'pay now' option will be linked to a URL

Thanks in advance
Dan

Comment: Very few email clients will allow that, linking out to a website that contains the terms/checkbox/confirmation button is a much safer approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory include a POST or GET form in the HTML body of your Email.

```
<form action="[url of action page]" method="[get or post]">
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms">
  <label for="terms">I accept the terms and conditions</label>
  
  <br>
  
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But given that email client support [is spotty at best](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/) this is not really recommendable.

You should probably include a link to a landing page instead where the customer can accept the terms & conditions.